# Angular lazy loading - don't see it is working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lazy-loading

I defined a lazy loading module.

this is SettingsRoutingModule module-

```
 const routes: Routes = [
        {
            path: '',
            component: SettingsStandaloneComponent,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '',
                    redirectTo: 'profile',
                    pathMatch: 'full'
                },
                {
                    path: 'profile',
                    component: SettingsProfileComponent
                },
                {
                    path: 'about',
                    component: SettingsAboutComponent
                },
                {
                    path: 'affiliations',
                    component: SettingsAffiliationsComponent
                },
                {
                    path: 'communication',
                    component: SettingsCommunicationComponent
                },
                {
                    path: 'notifications',
                    component: SettingsNotificationsComponent
                },
                {
                    path: 'proxies',
                    component: SettingsProxiesComponent
                },
                {
                    path: '**',
                    redirectTo: 'profile',
                    pathMatch: 'full'
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    @NgModule({
        imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
        exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class SettingsRoutingModule { }
```

in the AppRoutingModule module-

```
{ path: 'settings',
    loadChildren: './settings/settings.module#SettingsModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
},
```

in the prod production when a go to the network I don't see the "chunk.js" that everybody say that should appear". only two files that looks like- 0.34016a93d44e785b623a.js

In my localhost I see only "settings-settings-module.js"

Is it OK or does it mean that my module isn't lazy?

Comment: in your `./settings` folder, you should have an `index.ts` file having: `export { SettingsRoutingModule } from './settings.module.ts';` (assuming the above module is `settings.module.ts`, otherwise angular won't be able to know that it should lazy load it. Also, `loadChildren` should have: `./settings/settings.module#SettingsRoutingModule` instead, since it looks for the `index` file exporting the module named after `#`.

Comment: Are you sure? in the documentation is: id- const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'eager', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'eager', component: EagerComponent },
  { path: 'lazy', loadChildren: 'lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' }
];

Comment: in https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html I didn't see anything about a index.ts file..

Comment: as far as I can remember, the chunk file is created only as long as an index exports the module (that's a webpack behavior, if I'm not wrong). I've been using this system with lazy loaded modules since they came out and never had issues with that. Anyway, if you want to check whether the module is lazy loaded or not, just add a `console.log` in the lazy loaded module: if that's called onload, it's **not** lazyloaded, otherwise, if the log appears whenever you load that child specifically, it is.

Comment: Thanks! the ngOnInit if the SettingsComponent isn't get called on load. actually when I am in a different state I cannot even find the code in the dev tool.

Comment: @briosheje As i tried your options to check whether its lazy loaded or not using console.log in the lazy loaded module then its called onload not on lazy loading. But strange thing is i am able to see all the lazy loaded modules in the command prompt with their sizes like src_app_activities_activities_module_ts.js, src_app_membership_membership_module_ts.js etc . Can you please help me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 12):

Because of this option `"namedChunks": false` in your angular.json, you won't see the named chunks anymore, instead it displays hashed-value as the file name. This is due to recent improvements(not sure from when) in angular/cli.

Comment: great, thanks!! one more question- why do I see two js files?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is OK, We do not see chunk.js anymore. A lazy loaded module appears with its name in network tab as mentioned by you and it appears only once for the first time. To see it again, clear everything out by clicking the circle with a line through it in the upper left of the Network Tab:

[image: Lazy loaded module]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not filtering anything in Chrome Debugging tools in Network tab, it was driving me insane for a moment, I had everything set up perfectly.

Proof (I had 'fa' being filtered, that's why I couldn't see )
[image: Proof (I had 'fa' being filtered, that's why I couldn't see )]

After
[image: After]